# XML find all attribute values of a tag of a child

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-attribute

I want to get the text value of every child that has one and every attribute value of every child that has one. I can get the text values but I am having trouble getting the attribute values one by one and assigning each to a variable.

I have the following XML file:

```
<Transactions>
  <CardAuthorisation xmlns:xsi="http://...">
    <RecType>ADV</RecType>
    <AuthId>60874046</AuthId>
    <LocalDate>202008010000</LocalDate>
    <SettlementDate>202008</SettlementDate>
    <Card productid="16" PAN="64256700991593" product="MC" programid="AUST" branchcode="" />
  </CardAuthorisation>
</Transactions>
```

I have the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 
xFile = "test.XML"
xtree = et.parse(xFile)
xRoot = xtree.getroot()
for cardAuthorisation in xRoot.findall('CardAuthorisation'):
    recType = cardAuthorisation.find('./RecType').text
    authId = cardAuthorisation.find('./AuthId').text
    localDate = cardAuthorisation.find('./LocalDate').text
    settlementDate = cardAuthorisation.find('./SettlementDate').text
    #here is where I am having trouble with
    #pseudocode
    for every attribute in Card:
       card_productid = #the value of productid if not None else None
        .
        .
        .
       branchcode = #the value of branchcode if not None else None
```

This is my first time working with XML files, I have done a lot of research but none of them matches my use case. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all `<Card>` tags and each attribute/value of `<Card>`, you can do:

```
for c in cardAuthorisation.findall('Card'):
    for k, v in c.items():
        print(k, v)
```

Prints:

```
 productid 16
 PAN 64256700991593
 product MC
 programid AUST
 branchcode
```

Comment: thank you so much @Andrej Kesely, both of your answers solve the problem, you have saved me so much time :). I had no solution now I have two, please choose it between you two if I  shall give the check mark by FIFO standard or if I should help an uprising stackoverflow member :). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can access attributes of the "Card" element as follows:

```
card = cardAuthorisation.find('./Card')
for key in card.keys():
    print(key, card.get(key))
```

Comment: thank you so much @Alexandra Dudkina, both of your answers solve the problem, you have saved me so much time :). I had no solution now I have two, please choose it between you two if I  shall give the check mark by FIFO standard or if I should help an uprising stackoverflow member :). Thanks again!